# RegistryConnect Delphi

Tags: delphi

Приветствую. Есть следующее:

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create;
reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
if not reg.RegistryConnect('\\192.168.247.128') then
begin
showmessage('НЕ УДАЛОСЬ ((');
end;
reg.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
reg.OpenKey('IDENTITIES', false);
reg.WriteString('LAST USERNAME', 'HAHA');
```

он редактирует, но почему то на моем компьютере, а не на том к которому подключаюсь. сообщение

> "НЕ УДАЛОСЬ"

не вылетает, что свидетельствует об успешном подключении к чужому реестру. Служба удаленного реестра на том компе включена.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите так:

```
var 
  ErrStr:Pchar;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if not reg.RegistryConnect('\\192.168.247.128') then
  begin
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER or FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
      nil,GetLastError,LANG_USER_DEFAULT,@ErrStr,0,nil);
    ShowMessage(ErrStr);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

увидите в чем проблема. либо вручную вызовите RegConnectRegistry и смотрите ошибку аналогично:

```
//см. registry.pas TRegistry.RegistryConnect
Res:=RegConnectRegistry(PChar(UNCname), RootKey, TempKey);
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER or FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
  nil,Res,LANG_USER_DEFAULT,@ErrStr,0,nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все верно у вас редактироваться, даже при ошибке, ваш реестр. Тут надо бы ELSE и заключить редактирование в бегиненд